# SQL Server Express replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

Is it possible to replicate or mirror one database from SQL Server Express to SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TechNet Link](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM3sWk4PrSAhXMppQKHRNxAW8QFggaMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms151819(v%3Dsql.105).aspx&usg=AFQjCNF7kuzUTUhiwdcsov0QW-NasiE3JQ&sig2=tVbSt7WaMn7lY4Q_Z-SQbQ&bvm=bv.150729734,d.dGo)

> SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor.
>   However, merge replication allows changes to be replicated in both
>   directions between a Publisher and Subscriber. SQL Server Express does
>   not include SQL Server Agent, which is typically used to run
>   replication agents.

but what you can do is impose a replication process, create a trigger that will insert or update your replicated server